# Facebook Login and GraphMethodException: Unsupported (and unknown) get request

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, authorization

I followed facebook tutorial about Facebook Login on Android and it's ok. I can get user information that I need using User Access Token..but.. When I open my app, I see this in Log:

```
E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'XXXXX' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}
```

This is a response to a GET request that leaves automatically. (The ID is the right one).

Debugging my app token I get this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "app_id": "XXXXXXX",
    "type": "APP",
    "application": "AppName",
    "is_valid": true,
    "scopes": [
    ]
  }
}
```

It seems my app token doesn't give any authorization to my app ( "scopes": [ ] ). I think the problem is here but how can I resolve?
Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope :/ Personally, i abandoned the facebook login stuff